# I lost nginx.pid,it disappeared

Tags: nginx

Here is part of my `nginx.conf`:

```
pid        /www/nginx0836/nginx.pid;
```

While I restart nginx, in several seconds I run `ls /www/nginx0836` and it lists `nginx.pid`.
But after several seconds, running `ls /www/nginx0836` again, `nginx.pid` is not listed.
Why?
By the way, nginx server works well and when I run

```
ps -ef | grep "nginx: master process" | grep -v "grep" | awk -F ' ' '{print $2}'
```

then I can see nginx pid.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on a Centos Box using nginx/1.0.9.

Comment: Are you really using /www/nginx0836/nginx.pid, or is it actually somewhere under /var?  CentOS "helpfully" cleans up some directories under /var at intervals (/var/run comes to mind) and this might be what is biting you.

Comment: Try running strace on the started NGinx process. You can output the strace log to e.g. /tmp and go through afterwards to see what is going on Nginx wise (if this actually comes from nginx). If not then you have something from outside tampering with your pid file.

Comment: Missing pid file would not affect a running server, but you may encounter a problem if you 'stop it' or 'start nginx while one is already running'.

By the way, why not place the pid file on /run, which is likely on RAM?

Comment: First of all changing file location will make no impact on a list of systems like CentOS (RHEL) that are creating and managing this pidfile in sysV script. Can you show how are you starting and restarting nginx? Can you specify your OS?

Comment: It would be useful if you could paste your start/stop script. Maybe there is the problem

Answer (score 1):

try monitoring folder with incrond and log any changes with *$# $@* on that directory.
may be you will see something like puppet or an rsync deleting the pid file.

```
/www/nginx0836 IN_DELETE echo "$# $@"
```

it will log any delete event on directory

simpler than audit...

sorry the poor english

Answer (score -2):

Try default configuration for nginx, you will find similar problem [here](https://github.com/aws/opsworks-cookbooks/issues/164)